# What datatype to use in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sqldatatypes

I have been trying to identify which data type to use in a specific column, because I am encountering an error every time I import/export into my database.

I've tried `nvarchar`, `float`, `decimal` but I can't upload it all.

Here's an example of data I need to upload in my database:

```
P/VHL01-032013-85433
```

Here's the error:

> *Messages Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description:
>   "Unspecified error". (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> *Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with input column "TELEPHONE" (91) on input "Destination Input" (60). The column
>   status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for
>   the column.". (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> *Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "input "Destination Input"
>   (60)" failed because error code 0xC020907D occurred, and the error row
>   disposition on "input "Destination Input" (60)" specifies failure on
>   error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component. There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> *Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component
>   "Destination - tbl_billdelivery" (47) failed with error code
>   0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (60). The
>   identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method.
>   The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and
>   will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> *Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020. (SQL Server
>   Import and Export Wizard) –  Erl John Ejay 54 mins ago
>
> *Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on component "Source -
>   Sheet1$" (1) returned error code 0xC02020C4. The component returned a
>   failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The
>   meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error
>   is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: is that the entire string?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. Nothing in this question is asking to recommend an off-site library, tool, or resource.

Comment: This question would be more useful to others if you included the error you are encountering, as well as how you are trying to load the data.

Comment: I am encountering source to destination error when uploading. the list I provided are samples of each row supposedly to be uploaded

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: @ErlJohnEjay Please edit the question to include the error messages. Do not include them in comments.

Comment: Does the destination database field "Telephone" allow Nulls? Could the length of the Telephone field ever exceed the destination field?

Comment: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column." Well, that's pretty clear. It's normally that you're putting a NULL into a column of a database table that doesn't allow NULLs, but as [pointed out in answers to this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145958/the-value-violated-the-integrity-constraints-for-the-column) it could be any other kind of integrity constraint issue. Let's see the definition of the target table, including your integrity constraints.

Comment: I'm confused - why would you ever think the value `P/VHL01-032013-85433` would be a floating point number or a decimal value? That is a text value so the only valid data types will be char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar. Only you will know whether you need to account for unicode text in this column. That solved, you then need to identify what is the maximum possible length for that field. The current value is 20 characters. Could it exceed that? How large will it *realistically* get? Do not be lazy and specify `(8000)` or `(max)`. Finally, will that value *always* exist - ie is it nullable or not null

Comment: What are you importing? Excel file, csv, txt...?

Answer (score 0):

Once I encountered similar problem and I solved it with:

- installing **Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable** (For office 2010)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

- installing **2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components** (For office 2007)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734