# The value violated the integrity constraints for the column while executing SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I have created `SSIS` package which basically extract the dirty data from the table and using `DQS Cleansing Transformation`  clean the data and load into tables according to `Lookup Transformation` criteria. I am getting below error at the end of the process.

```
Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, CustomersDirtyNoMatch [109]: SSIS Error 
Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
Error: 0xC020901C at Data Flow Task, CustomersDirtyNoMatch [109]: There was an error with CustomersDirtyNoMatch.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[CustomerKey] on CustomersDirtyNoMatch.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".
Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, CustomersDirtyNoMatch [109]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "CustomersDirtyNoMatch.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "CustomersDirtyNoMatch.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "CustomersDirtyNoMatch" (109) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (122). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

Screen Shot of my Data Flow
[image]

For more information please refer this 
[document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2WSqlnDDmo1MzFUS0FlU1RyTDA)

Here's a table definition

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomersDirty (
    CustomerKey INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FullName NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    StreetAddress NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    Updated INT NULL,
    CleanCustomerKey INT NULL);

CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomersClean (
    CustomerKey INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FullName NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    StreetAddress NVARCHAR(200) NULL );

CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomersDirtyMatch (
  CustomerKey INT ,
  FullName NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
  StreetAddress_Source NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
  StreetAddress NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
  StreetAddress_Status NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
  StreetAddress_Confidence NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
  StreetAddress_Reason NVARCHAR(4000) NULL,
  Updated INT NULL,
  CleanCustomerKey INT NULL,
  Record_Status NVARCHAR(100) NULL );

CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomersDirtyNoMatch ( 
    CustomerKey INT , 
    FullName NVARCHAR(200) NULL, 
    StreetAddress_Source NVARCHAR(200) NULL, 
    StreetAddress NVARCHAR(200) NULL, 
    StreetAddress_Status NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
    StreetAddress_Confidence NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
    StreetAddress_Reason NVARCHAR(4000) NULL, 
    Updated INT NULL, 
    CleanCustomerKey INT NULL, 
    Record_Status NVARCHAR(100) NULL );
```

As recommended I did some change in configuration. I have added `Flat File Destination` adapter at the end of `CustomerDirtyNoMatch` destination adapter. Still data is not inserted in table though error data inserted in flat file.

Please refer this [flat file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2WSqlnDDmo1YWV2NTZNazQyaEE)

updated data flow

[image]

Comment: What about the table that the unmatched customers are being inserted into? Could you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for this table including any constraints on it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145958/the-value-violated-the-integrity-constraints-for-the-column/19786740

Comment: No I checked already

Comment: Recommend configuring the error output for the CustomersDirtyNoMatch component and putting the rows which generate this error into a text file so you can examine them.

Comment: What are you inserting into `CustomersDirtyNoMatch.CustomerKey`? The error basically indicates that you are inserting something non numeric in there.

Comment: Adding an error destination will not make the data insert into your table. It's just a troubleshooting step. The error file shows that that the value for CustomerKey is blank. Which shouldn't be a problem if `CustomerKey` is nullable. Since you don't ever have a customerkey in this case, the most straightforward solution is to remove the column altogether from this table

Comment: `CustomerKey` was the primary key I removed because of this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145958/the-value-violated-the-integrity-constraints-for-the-column/19786740). I don't understand why even flat file doesn't include `CustomerKey`? Is it because `CleanCustomerKey` has data? But actually it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Firstly; your table script does not indicate it is a primary key. Next time post the full table script (and post it in the original question). So where does customer key come from ? I can't look in your package but I'll take a guess and say that the _exact matches_ step introduces it and if there is no match there is no customer key. So clearly you cannot a primary key column in a table with a blank value. There are a lot of basic misunderstandings here

Comment: I have posted table definition. `CustomerKey` is coming from `CustomerDirty OLE DB Source`