# Cannot load data from Excel into SQL using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I am trying to import an excel file into the SQL server using SSIS package, but every time I try to upload this file some rows from the last don't get uploaded, to be precise 55107 should be uploaded but only 54990 gets uploaded. 117 rows are creating some problem and am not able to figure out why is that so. Please help me out in understanding this error message so that I can resolve the issue. Below is the error message I'm getting:

> SSIS package "C:\Users\A670814\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services Project1\NDCS Towers.dtsx" starting.
>   Information: 0x4004300A at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
>
> Information: 0x4004300A at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
>   Warning: 0x80049304 at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
>   Information: 0x40043006 at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
>   Information: 0x40043007 at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
>   Information: 0x4004300C at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
>   Error: 0xC0202009 at NDCS tower, OLE DB Destination [280]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
>   Error: 0xC020901C at NDCS tower, OLE DB Destination [280]: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Copy of ID] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".
>
> Error: 0xC0209029 at NDCS tower, OLE DB Destination [280]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0047022 at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (280) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (293). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC02020C4 at NDCS tower, Excel Source [156]: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>   Error: 0xC0047038 at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Excel Source returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   Information: 0x40043008 at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
>   Information: 0x4004300B at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination" wrote 55107 rows.
>   Information: 0x40043009 at NDCS tower, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
>   Task failed: NDCS tower
>
> Warning: 0x80019002 at NDCS Towers: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (6) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
>
> SSIS package "C:\Users\A670814\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services Project1\NDCS Towers.dtsx" finished: Failure.

Comment: Check if you have a blank row in excel file

Answer (score 0):

> There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Copy of ID] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".

It looks there are many rows where `[Copy of ID]` column is null, or there are some constraints on the `[Copy of ID]` column in SQL server that are violated in some rows in the excel files.

Try deleting rows that contains no data in `[Copy of ID]` column, or you can filter them by adding a conditional split component and filter on the following consition

```
ISNULL([Copy of ID])
```

Or you can access to the destination SQL table using Sql server management studio, and go to the SQL table design mode, and check the option `Allow null` for the column `[Copy of ID]`

*Similar Question with many useful answers: [The value violated the integrity constraints for the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145958/the-value-violated-the-integrity-constraints-for-the-column/19786740)*

Comment: The Copy of ID column is supposed to be Primary key column, I have double checked the values in the column, there are no duplicates and there are no null values.

Comment: Check if the destination table already contains data, check that columns are mapped correctly

Comment: and what is the data type of this column in the excel file? is that column identity or not?

Comment: I got the query resolved, the ID column contained some characters too but for the ID column in SQL if it is primary key, it should contain only numbers.

Comment: @ApoorvDeshmukh Hope that i helped you. Good luck