# Export excel data from one excel sheet into 4 different tables in SQL using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, excel-2010, etl

I tried importing data from one excel sheet into 4 different tables in Microsoft studio using SSIS. I used execute sql task to drop and recreate the tables, EXCEL Source,  data-conversion to convert the data and OLEDB destination.

but I get the following errors:

> [OLE DB Destination [168]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [168]] Error: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Copy of SSN] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [168]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (168) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (181). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

... can some one please help

Comment: You have to show what you have tried, describe your package or add a screenshot of the control flow

Comment: Is your flow control sequential or parallel?

Comment: You probably have empty rows at the end of your Excel file. Check the answers to this question for several good solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145958/the-value-violated-the-integrity-constraints-for-the-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The value violated the integrity constraints for the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145958/the-value-violated-the-integrity-constraints-for-the-column)

Comment: Thanks folks. Its been fixed and yes I was because of the constraints I had on my destination table. Thanks for your contributions